# Should containers in React be reusable?

Tags: reactjs

I have two containers, where most components of them are same but some are not. So I extract same components into a new container and use `if-else` to give them their unique components. Is this a good way to deal with containers? To clarify, I add below code.

```
// container A has below components
<Component1 data={dataA1} style={style} />
<Component2 data={dataA2} />
<Component3 data={dataA3} />

// container B has below components
<Component1 data={dataB1} style={style} />
<Component2 data={dataB2} />
<Component4 data={dataB4} />

// A and B have same components, so I made a new container C
<Component1 data={is this container A ? dataA1 : dataB1} style={style} />
<Component2 data={is this container A ? dataA2 : dataB2} />
is this container A ? <Component3 data={dataA3} /> : <Component4 data={dataB4} />
```

I feel like this is not good, though it has something reused. And if we have another container, this structure will be too unreadable and hard to maintain because of too many uses of `if-else`.

So what do you think about this situation? Any comments are appreciated and welcome. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried just using react children with this? like in your container render you have `{this.props.children}` and then in the render of your container `<Container><Component1 /><Component2 />... etc`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I tried this way but I don't think it make more sense than just using 2 containers without another common one, `container C` in my example.

Comment: why does it not make more sense?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Since the common container has nothing but just returning `<div>{this.props.children}</div>` and everything else is in their own containers. So it's not necessary?

Comment: no thats not what I was saying. the container I'm assuming is doing some special stuff.. has some common functionality. so you specify what the children are to the container but the container extends functionality

Comment: @JohnRuddell Got it. Good point. Thanks! But do you agree if there is no specific functionality, it's unnecessary to extract a common one?

Comment: If you have to re-type elements then you should probably make it a component. like for instance a layout component that renders a header and a footer and then the content in the middle being children. its really just contextual to what you are trying to do and what the functionality currently is. I'd need to see a real example to be able to help further

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think I had a solution for my situation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `component` should be reusable, that's one of the reason why it has been created that way.

But **reuse** has a cost, which is **coupling**.

Probably your container will not end up with data difference only, they will have different logic, will dispatch different functions or call different API.

If data is the whole difference for sure, create a factory for these `components` which will receive the container/data and return the appropriate component. (see `factory method design pattern`)

Otherwise, I would totally create different components for that.

Comment: In my example, all components are reusable. Yes, there are some differences in structure and functions not just data for containers but they all have a lot of same components, some with same data some with different data. But I guess for my case, you agree with that I shouldn't create a common container like container C in my example, right?

Comment: Probably I would not choose that approach exactly,  as I suggest, you can create a more factory like, for that to hold these "if" logic. (as long as it can become more complicate, otherwise forget about container C / factory)